# I am stuck with an output in C ( Multi-dimensional array operations)

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int arr[3][2]={2,3,4,5,6,7};

    printf("%d\n",arr);
    printf("%d\n",arr[1]);
    printf("%d",arr[1][2]);
}
```

The above code when compiled in Borland Turbo C++ gives the output

```
8682
8686
6
```

I don't understand how this program works. I understand that while printing `arr` it returns the base address as 8682 and `arr[1]` returns next address location 8686 (integer is 4 bytes) but why is `arr[1][2]` not flashing an error as `arr[1][2]` is out of bounds?

Comment: "How this program works" - it doesn't, printing a pointer with `%d` is undefined behavior. Start by changing the format specifier(s) to `%p` when appropriate and casting the pointers to `(void *)`, and then we can speak again.

Comment: If you want bounds checking, the language is Turbo Pascal.  C assumes the programmer knows what they are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it's undefined behavior. However, if you look at how array indices are treated, you will see why it's working.

```
arr
|
v
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

arr[0]
|
v
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

            arr[1]
            |
            v
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

               arr[1][0]
               |
               v
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

                           arr[1][2]
                           |
                           v
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, errors are not thrown for out of bounds array accesses - in fact it doesn't even make any check! Instead the system will just access whatever happens to be at that spot in memory (one of the major dangers of C programs).

Here's an explanation of what is happening here. Take this code here:

```
arr[1][2]
```

What happens internally actually looks like this:

```
*(arr + 1 * 2 + 2)  // the 2 comes from the second dimension size of the array
```

The 2D array internally is stored as a one-dimensional array with each row coming after the previous row:

```
arr[3][2] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
// is the same as
arr[6] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

The math from `arr[1][2]` works out to accessing `arr[5]`, which is why you get `6` as the value.

Comment: `arr[1][2]` is the same as `*( *(a + 1) + 2)`. The equivalence is: `a[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(a+i)+j)`.

Answer (score 0):

> why arr[1][2] is not flashing an error as arr[1][2] is out of bound

if my memory serves me right, C wont complain about array out of bounds errors. It will instead simply allow you to go out of bounds.